# Do powers of 2 routinely neighbor powers of 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let me write the question more precisely first: Is it true that for every $n\in\Bbb N$ there exists an $m\geq n$ and a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $2^m = 3^k\pm 1$.

I have tried various modular arithmetic methods, but none of them seem to help me solve my question.

Comment: Where is n coming into play?  If you are saying $2^m = 3^n +/- 1 $. Then I'd suggest looking at some powers of 3 first.  If you mean congruent mid n then please rephrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the case. In fact, $8$ and $9$ are the only consecutive prime powers. 
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture